# My mock function are not called after simulate change input type=file

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Good day, I need to test my function `handleChangeLoadFile` that situated in class component. I try to write some test but it don't work for me. Еhe test lets me know that my mocked function is not being called, and why it is not called I cannot understand. I will be grateful if you help me.

My test:

```
it('should call handleChangeLoadFile 1 times and complete all mock function', () => {
    let mockFn = jest.fn();
    CreatePostHeader.prototype.handleChangeLoadImage = mockFn;
    const component = mountWithoutStore(<CreatePostHeader {...props} {...propsFunc}/>);
    const createPostComponent = component.find('CreatePostHeader');
    // createPostComponent.instance().handleChangeLoadFile = jest.fn();
    const changeButton = createPostComponent.find('.invisible_input_file').first();
    const file = new File(['dummy content'], 'example.png', {type: 'image/png'});
    changeButton.simulate('change', {target: {files: [file]}});
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

The element which call function

```
<input
   type="file"
   accept=".txt, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .odt, .ott, .ods, .ots"
   className="invisible invisible_input_file" ref={this.props.inputHiddenFile}
   onChange={this.handleChangeLoadFile}
/>
```

My function:

```
handleChangeLoadFile = (event) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
            const file = event.target.files[i];
            if (validateFile(file)) {
                const typeFile = getUploadFileFormat(file);
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = () => {
                    if (_.size(this.state.files) < 5) {
                        this.setState({files: {...this.state.files,
                            [file.name]: {
                                title: file.name,
                                content_type: formatAllowS3[typeFile],
                                document: reader.result
                            }
                        }
                        }, () => this.props.changeItemInState('createPostHeader', this.state));
                    } else {
                        this.props.showNotification('error', this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'createPost.notification.uploadFileCount' }));
                    }
                };
            } else {
                if (file.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                    this.props.showNotification('error', this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'createPost.notification.uploadFileSize' }));
                } else {
                    this.props.showNotification('error', this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'createPost.notification.uploadFileFormat' }));
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried `component.update()` (assuming this is your main component you're testing/rendering here)? This forces a resync inside of Eznyme of the rendered component as per [docs here](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class component, change your mock to spy (and remember you can't spy on arrow functions):

```
const mockFn = jest.spyOn(CreatePostHeader.prototype, 'handleChangeLoadImage');
```

You can add your `mockImplementation` of course, if you like.

If you have a functional component, you have to test the effects of the function, not the implementation itself (which is even better), eg.

```
const mockEvent = {target: {files: ['mock']}};
const mockChangeItemInState = jest.fn();

const component = mountWithoutStore(<CreatePostHeader {...props} changeItemInState={mockChangeItemInState}/>);

component.find(/*your input*/).simulate('change', mockEvent);

expect(mockChangeItemInState).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/*something you want*/);
```

I kind of oversimplified it, but you get the idea...

Comment: handleChangeLoadImage is not on the prototype and this won't work.

Comment: I've added an option for func component, edited my answer...